# Translating local coordinate system to world system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, translation

In QGIS we needed to measure an area with a total station but that time without a calibrated world coordinate system (no calibration points available). The North was only roughly oriented by compass.

Finally we now made it to get some of our calibration points measured by GNSS so that we now have them within the world system.

Is there a plugin for QGIS, that I can use to recalculate all other points based on that few ones which we now have in the world system? I guess the elevation is easy to recalculate based on the hight difference but how is it with the X/Y and the North?

Comment: There's the native tool `translate geometry`.

Comment: I know this but therefore I would need the transformation parameter but I only have two coordinate systems where 5 points are the same in each one and I want to set 1 point in system 1 is point 1 in system 2 and after I would automatically recalibrate all other points into the world system...